# An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListTagsForResource operation: One or more parameter value is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

I am trying to run an AWS cli command of the following form

```
aws configservice list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:123456789:cluster/xxxxxxxxxxx--region ap-southeast-2
```

I am recieving the following error
`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListTagsForResource operation: One or more parameter value is invalid`

I triple checked the resource-arn and have tried several but no luck.

Doco for this endpoint is here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/list-tags-for-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

```
aws configservice list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-2:123456789:cluster/xxxxxxxxxxx--region ap-southeast-2
```

It should have a space between ARN and --region.

If it is not the case, I think you are using the wrong API. It should be this one

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cli/latest/reference/eks/list-tags-for-resource.html

Change configservice to eks and try again